# How to generate all possible combinations of K instances of N objects in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, combinatorics

How to generate all possible combinations of K instances of N objects in Matlab?

For example, if we have N=3 objects A, B and C, and wish to generate combinations of K=2 instances, we should get

```
AA
AB
AC
BA
BB
BC
CA
CB
CC
```

I.e. this is how figures in a number combinate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fullfact`:

```
fullfact([3 3])
```

This will produce all the combinations of 3 elements in the first row and 3 elements in the second row, resulting with:

```
 1     1
 2     1
 3     1
 1     2
 2     2
 3     2
 1     3
 2     3
 3     3
```

Comment: To get characters use `s='A':'C';K=2;s(fullfact(repmat(numel(s),k,1)))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `allcomb` from matlab file exchange:

```
allcomb(['A','B','C'],['A','B','C'])
```

[download](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb)

A more generalized method:

```
s='A':'D'
k=3
e=repmat({s},1,k)
allcomb(e{:})
```